# Why .doc automaticly downloads, but not shown in <iframe>?

Tags: html, css, iframe

The problem is - when I input url with .png or .pdf it has been shown in iframe>. I can scroll it, read etc.
But when I insert an url which has docx or xls file (ex. "http://www.exampleimage.docx")  - it automatikly aploads by browser, and not shown in iframe>.But i want to see content of .docx file in iframe like i do with pdf.
What to do or where to search guys?

here is part of my code:

```
 <iframe   src={{attachmentUrl}} width="468" height="468" frameborder="0">
    Click on attachment please.
</iframe>
```

Comment: As far as I know no browser can directly display a .docx file (except IE/Edge maybe?) so they revert back to their standard behavior and download what ever file they get.

Comment: You can get plugins for viewing .docx documents inline in the browser. For Firefox, see https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/docs-online-viewer/ or for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-online-viewer/gmpljdlgcdkljlppaekciacdmdlhfeon?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your url i.e, 
"https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${YOUR_URL}&embedded=true" and then add to iframe:

```js
 <iframe
   className="doc"
   src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${YOUR_URL}&embedded=true`}
 />
```